# SQL Server - Divide sum of columns

Tags: sql-server, math, division

I am trying to divide sum of two columns and SQL is not giving me precise number in decimal.Please check below queries. I don't know what I am missing here.

Data type of PAYEE and TOTAL is decimal(10,2)

Queries

```
SELECT SUM(PAYEES) AS SUM_PAYEES,SUM(TOTAL) AS SUM_TOTAL,SUM(PAYEES)/SUM(TOTAL) AS DIVISION FROM #ADMIN_FEE_1

SUM_PAYEES  SUM_TOTAL   DIVISION
19940.00    59435.00    0.335492

SELECT 19940.00/59435.00 AS DIVISION

DIVISION
0.3354925548
```

Is this a bug in SQL Server? Is there way to get correct answer?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what are the types of the payees/total fields? because the `sum/sum` version is bound by whatever typeconversions those fields call for. your `select 1994` is just dividing two hard-coded floats, so you get a float as a result.

Comment: You can implicitly cast to a type -->  / CONVERT(SUM(TOTAL) AS DECIMAL(18,2))

Comment: @MarcB I just updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT SUM(PAYEES) AS SUM_PAYEES,
SUM(TOTAL) AS SUM_TOTAL,
cast(SUM(PAYEES) as decimal(18,10))/cast(SUM(TOTAL) AS DECIMAL(18,10)) AS DIVISION 
FROM #ADMIN_FEE_1;
```

EDIT2:

tested Query

```
SELECT SUM(19940.00) AS SUM_PAYEES,SUM(59435.00) AS SUM_TOTAL,cast(SUM(19940.00) as decimal(18,10))/
cast(SUM(59435.00) as decimal(18,10)) AS DIVISION
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to `decimal` type like below

```
SELECT SUM(PAYEES) AS SUM_PAYEES,
SUM(TOTAL) AS SUM_TOTAL,
CAST(SUM(PAYEES)/SUM(TOTAL) AS DECIMAL(12,10)) AS DIVISION 
FROM #ADMIN_FEE_1;
```

Comment: this is giving me division as - 0.335492000000000000. I want 0.3354925548.

Comment: Try changing the precision value